# The import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication can not be resolved

Tags: spring, mongodb, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to implement a maven project using mongodb.The following code is provided by STS. I am unable to detect the eroor. pom.xml is perfect.Why this jar is showing an errorin 2nd and 10th lines?

```
package com.example.demo;
**import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;**
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MongoexampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        **SpringApplication.run(MongoexampleApplication.class, args);**
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `mvn install` on command line work ?

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace as well as your pom.xml

Comment: I would guess that Maven has corrupted the `spring-boot` jar when it downloaded it. Try deleting `org/springframework/boot/spring-boot` from your Maven cache and building your application again.

Comment: @Gautam mvn clean is working perfectly.but, mvn install is showing error as the following.C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.0.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Comment: @KrishnaMohan, then try doing what Andy says. As a general rule, try to resolve compilation errors from the command line first. The IDE at times adds its own layer of errors, so its difficult to figure out if the error is genuine.

Comment: @Andy it helps. Thankyou